# how to split and sort data in array to nsmutabledictionary

Tags: ios, nsarray, nsdictionary

i have array data like this.

```
  animals = @[@"Bear", @"Black Swan", @"Buffalo", @"Camel", @"Cockatoo", @"Dog", @"Donkey", @"Emu", @"Giraffe", @"Greater Rhea", @"Hippopotamus", @"Horse", @"Koala", @"Lion", @"Llama", @"Manatus", @"Meerkat", @"Panda", @"Peacock", @"Pig", @"Platypus", @"Polar Bear", @"Rhinoceros", @"Seagull", @"Tasmania Devil", @"Whale", @"Whale Shark", @"Wombat"];
```

and how to grouping by first letter to nsmutabledictionary. (Depend on array data) like this.

```
 animals = @{@"B" : @[@"Bear", @"Black Swan", @"Buffalo"],
            @"C" : @[@"Camel", @"Cockatoo"],
            @"D" : @[@"Dog", @"Donkey"],
            @"E" : @[@"Emu"],
            @"G" : @[@"Giraffe", @"Greater Rhea"],
            @"H" : @[@"Hippopotamus", @"Horse"],
            @"K" : @[@"Koala"],
            @"L" : @[@"Lion", @"Llama"],
            @"M" : @[@"Manatus", @"Meerkat"],
            @"P" : @[@"Panda", @"Peacock", @"Pig", @"Platypus", @"Polar Bear"],
            @"R" : @[@"Rhinoceros"],
            @"S" : @[@"Seagull"],
            @"T" : @[@"Tasmania Devil"],
            @"W" : @[@"Whale", @"Whale Shark", @"Wombat"]};
```

Thank you.!!

Answer (score 1):

Its very easy to be done yourself, but anyway check this piece of code

```
NSArray *words = @[@"AS", @"CS", @"AQ", @"CA", @"SA"];
NSMutableDictionary *dic = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
for (NSString *word in words) {

    if (word.length > 0) {

        NSString *firstChar = [word substringToIndex:1];
        NSMutableArray *contents = dic[firstChar];
        if (!contents) {
            contents = [NSMutableArray array];
            dic[firstChar] = contents;
        }

        [contents addObject:word];
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it yourself. Iterate over the array, get the first character from the item, check if it exists in the dictionary, add to the array if it does and insert a new array if not.

Any alternative approach would be using a 3rd party library which offered this feature.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *animals = @[@"Bear", @"Black Swan", @"Buffalo", @"Camel", @"Cockatoo", @"Dog", @"Donkey", @"Emu", @"Giraffe", @"Greater Rhea", @"Hippopotamus", @"Horse", @"Koala", @"Lion", @"Llama", @"Manatus", @"Meerkat", @"Panda", @"Peacock", @"Pig", @"Platypus", @"Polar Bear", @"Rhinoceros", @"Seagull", @"Tasmania Devil", @"Whale", @"Whale Shark", @"Wombat"];

NSMutableDictionary *animalDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

for (NSString *animal in animals) {
    NSString *firstLetter = [animal substringToIndex:1];
    NSMutableArray *letterArray = [animalDict objectForKey:firstLetter];
    if (!letterArray) {
        letterArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:animal];
        [animalDict setObject:letterArray forKey:firstLetter];
    } else {
        [letterArray addObject:animal];
        [letterArray sortUsingSelector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
    }
}

NSLog(@"%@", animalDict);
```